# Split dataframe column into two columns based on delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, delimiter

I am preprocessing text for classification, and I import my dataset like this:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('lyrics.csv', delimiter = '\t', quoting = 2)
```

`dataset` prints on terminal:

```
                                 lyrics,classification
0    I should have known better with a girl like yo...
1    You can shake an apple off an apple tree\nShak...
2    It's been a hard day's night\nAnd I've been wo...
3    Michelle, ma belle\nThese are words that go to...
```

however, when I inspect the variable `dataset` closer using `spyder`, I see that I have only one column, instead of the desired two columns.

[image]

considering that lyrics themselves have commas and  ","  delimiter would not work,

how do I correct my dataframe above in order to have:

1) one column for `lyrics`

2) one column for `classification`

with correspondent data for each row?

Comment: set `delimiter=','`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your lyrics themselves do not contain commas (they most likely do), then you can use `read_csv` with `delimiter=','`.

However, if that is not an option, you could use `str.rsplit`:

```
dataset.iloc[:, 0].str.rsplit(',', expand=True)
```

---

```
df

                               lyrics,classification
0  I should have known better with a girl like yo...
1                              You can shake an...,0
2                  It's been a hard day's night...,0

df = df.iloc[:, 0].str.rsplit(',', 1, expand=True)
df.columns = ['lyrics', 'classification']
df

                                              lyrics classification
0  I should have known better with a girl like yo...              0
1                                You can shake an...              0
2                    It's been a hard day's night...              0
```

Comment: something's wrong here...because with your solution my dataset gets all messed up. every line gets a column, and not every lyrics.

Comment: @data_garden Try this: `.str.rsplit(',', 1, expand=True)` # note the 1 there

Comment: @data_garden It's obvious to me now your lyrics had commas after each line, so `rsplit` was performing multiple splits. If you set `nsplits` to `1`, only one partition is made, and this will fix your issue.